# How to style text in an item of a breadcrumbs trail?

Tags: jquery, html, css, string, replace

On one Wordpress site I'm using the plugin Breadcrumbs NavXT to create a breadcrumbs trail. Now two or three different items I need to make a change to thickness of the font of a single word.

This is the structure of the breadcrumbs trail:

```
<div class="breadcrumbs" xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#">
    <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
        <a class="home" href="#" title="home" property="v:title" rel="v:url">home</a>
    </span>
    <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
        <a class="some title" href="#" title="Some Title" property="v:title" rel="v:url">some title</a>
    </span>
    <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
            <a class="some other title" href="#" title="Some Other Title" property="v:title" rel="v:url">some other title</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

So basically I thought I would need to insert a span wrapping the respective word like this:

```
<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
    <a class="some title" href="#" title="Some Title" property="v:title" rel="v:url">some <span style="font-size:normal;">title</span></a>
</span>
```

I thought this would best be done with Jquery fetching the text string, in this example `some title`, and replace it with `some <span style="font-size:normal;">title</span>` (or using a class inside the span element)

What do you think? Any ideas on how to set up the script?

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS selector...

```
div.breadcrumbs span:last-child > a {
font-size: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but wouldn't that just work on the entire title? And what if it wouldn't be the last breadcrumb but the middle one (I've added another breadcrumb to make it clear)?

Comment: Yes. You will have to wrap anything that you would like to change the style of. You could do it through javascript and split the string and insert a wrapping node, but it's so much easier to just use markup from the beginning to do it.